# Append a word after input value in the input field

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have a input field,

I want to make the function acts like this way

When user inputs

```
`100` -> it should show `100 people`
`10000` -> it should show `10,000 people`
```

As you can see the word `people` always followed by the number

## Filter

I tried to add `people` by filter, but no knowing how to apply it on the text field.

```
app.filter('plusPeople function() {
    return function(value){
        return value + " People";
    }

})
```

Comment: You want to show the `people` word in the input box on change/blur?

Answer (score 2):

Try `ng-blur()`

Html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="people" ng-blur="append()"></input>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.people = '';

$scope.append = function() {
     $scope.people = $scope.people + " people";
};
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comment below, assign the number to a different scope and keep the `$scope.people` as it is.

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/UXAA8IfAvTfebJ6P6C1p?p=preview) here.

Comment: Sorry this is not the one I want. I want to append the string "  people" in the end of the input value, but I don't want to pollute the value of `$scope.people `. It should keep the integer value only.

Comment: thank you so much but your example is not I need , so sorry. If user types 100, user should see `100 people` on the text field,  but the model value should be 100, not `100 people`. I need it show on the text field, not somewhere else :D

Comment: I think the angular masking is what I need, But I need to figure out how to use it haha

Comment: @user3675188, did you look at the demo? It does exactly what you said.

Comment: Hi I think this example is much closer to what I need :)